# Вместо русских букв выводится что-то другое

Tags: python, pycharm

Вместо русских букв выводится что-то другое в Pycharm!
При чем с английскими все нормально.
Вообще изначально я не добавлял в начале

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

и

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
```

Но тогда у меня вообще была ошибка

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd0' in file 
C:\Users\staykoks\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\task_1.py 
on line 9, but no encoding declared
```

Помогите пожалуйста)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При чем в VS этот же код работает нормально

Comment: Это может помочь https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/working-with-consoles.html

Comment: Откройте командную строку, введите chcp, нажмите Enter, что пишет?

Comment: Текущая кодовая страница: 866

Comment: Посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131654/using-utf-8-encoding-chcp-65001-in-command-prompt-windows-powershell-window

Answer (score 2):

В правом нижнем углу окна Pycharm на вашем скриншоте видно, что вы используете Python 2.7:

[image: Скриншот]

В Python 2 `print` - не функция, а оператор, параметры в него передаются без скобок. Он воспринимает параметр `print("f(x) = ", f, "при x = ", x)` как кортеж `("f(x) = ", f, "при x = ", x)`

Варианты исправления:

1. ***Настоятельно рекомендую*** установить и использовать Python 3 вместо Python 2
2. Если все-таки по какой-то причину нужно использовать Python 2, то:

   - можно убрать скобки: `print "f(x) = ", f, "при x = ", x`
   - или добавить импорт `from __future__ import print_function`, тогда `print` будет работать как в Python 3 (но других современных возможностей Python 3, естественно, не будет). Ну и добавлять строку `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` в начале программы при использовании не ascii символов в коде в Python2 обязательно, в Python3 при использовании кодировки utf-8 - не обязательно (фактически не нужно).

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему у вас кодировка консоли не соответствует UTF-8

По умолчанию pycharm ставит системную кодировку для консоли. Попробуйте выставить вручную.

1. В Settings(Ctrl+Alt+S) перейдите в Editor |
   General | Console.
2. Попробуйте поставить UTF-8 или windows-1251 в выпадающем меню "Default encoding"
3. OK для сохранения

Comment: Не помогает, перепробовал все популярные кодировки. Вообще ничего не меняется, так же выводится  \xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8

Answer (score 0):

Могу ошибаться, но, по-моему, у вас во второй строке после `#` лишний пробел.

Попробуйте проверить

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```